# Android live wallpaper: How to give feedback while new settings are loaded?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I created a live wallpaper which is relatively memory-intensive. You can choose between multiple themes.

When a new theme is chosen, the nescessary bitmaps are being stored to the memory. During this process the application just takes no input from the user.

Is there any possibility to give the user a feedback during this cache process? Maybe a progress bar or a hourglass?

Greetings,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use an [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that , it has the `onProgressUpdate` function like in this example:

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```